# How to show only one field of database column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I´m new to PHP. I´m able to show all the fields belonging to a column (bla1, bla2, bla3, bla4), but I want to show only "bla2" or "bla4", for example. I want to select the field in the "echo" part, not in the "SELECT...". How can I do it? Here´s my code (simplified), thanks in advance.

```
table_name  
    table_id | table_title  
           1 | bla1  
           2 | bla2  
           3 | bla3  
           4 | bla4  

class DB {
    private $mysqli;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db_name');
        if($this->mysqli->connect_error){
            die($this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        $this->mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    }

public function getRowz($sql) {
    $items = array();
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
    $this->checkError();
    while( $row = $result->fetch_object()){
    $items[] = $row;
    }
    return $items;
}

$db = new DB();  
$list = $db->getRowz("SELECT * FROM table_name");  
foreach($list as $item){  
    echo $item->table_title;  
}
```

Comment: Also, you might wanna change the `getRowz` function to do `yield $row` instead of capturing it in an array which you are returning anyways. Its called memory efficiency.

Comment: If you want to show only every 2nd row, then you need to come up with a selection method. Either (A) filter out every table_id divisible by two, or (B) use a for loop instead of foreach, or (C) perhaps a counter in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Then filter it with PHP:

```
foreach($list as $item){  
  if($item->table_id == 2 || $item->table_id == 4){
    echo $item->table_title;  
  }
}
```